# Required client entitlement required?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, entitlements

I have a wkwebview and I selected the checkbox 'inline playback' which is suppose to make any video in the wkwebview to not autoplay and stay in the webpage and not go full screen.

This worked fine for me until my Xcode updated to 11!

I now get the following error but it lets the auto playing video to go full screen, when before it wouldn't.

```
2019-09-27 22:26:43.654625-0400 RPD[3848:126819] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x600000c9c7b0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Required client entitlement is missing"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x7fe141f30d60; requestedReason: MediaPlayback; reason: MediaPlayback; flags: PreventTaskSuspend | PreventTaskThrottleDown | WantsForegroundResourcePriority>;
    }
}
```

I added the capability 'Background Modes' but enabling Audio, Airplay, Picture in picture does not do anything.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem; it seems to happen while loading and/or trying to play audio after it has been loaded. Did you already find a solution?

Comment: @dndr, haven't found a solution yet and I want one so badly. Please post a answer here if you do find a solution as I need it!

Comment: Checking in on this. I don't suppose you ever figured it out?

Comment: @MikeyWard, I did :) it went away with update, submitted app to app store, it works now.

Comment: @MikeyWard what did you  update?